# how can i switch an element of an array with another array?

Tags: c++, arrays

so far I have this. how would I put for example 1(element) in the first array into the third array?
can i do an index number which will copy then i can rotate?
I also want to be able to print out the information. im working in c++ and im stuck. any help will be greatly apreciated.

```
int a[3] ={1,2,3}; 
int b[3] ={0,0,0}; 
int c[3] ={0,0,0}; 

b << a.delete(1);
```

for example,
how can i make it so

```
int a[3]= {001}
and  c[3]= {023}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: What do you mean rotate? You can assign an element of an array to the value of an element in another array quite simply like `c[0] = a[0];`

Answer (score 1):

You can "switch" elements simply by this:

```
std::swap( a[0], c[0] );
```

Now you can "rotate" elements in array a, but you will have to write a function to swap element by element in that array. Or you can use std::vector instead and use its ability to insert/delete elements in arbitrary position.
For example:

```
std::vector<int> a { 1, 2, 3 };

if( !a.empty() ) {
   int temp = a.front();
   a.erase( a.begin() );
   a.push_back( temp );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you do realize that a[3] and c[3] do NOT exist?  only a[0] a[1] and a[2]

Comment: This isn't really an answer. I'd make it a comment.

Comment: I see your point, but if he was actually trying it and "getting stuck", then maybe that was his "bug"

Answer (score 0):

You just assign it

```
c[0] = a[1];
```

that puts the second element of `a` into the first element of `c`

if you want to swap, you can use a temp variable

```
int temp = c[0];
c[0] = a[1];
a[1] = temp;
```

Comment: so they would basically swap?

Comment: @Ryankid, no, whatever was in a[1] would be in both a[1] and c[0].

Comment: how and would i get that to display when it runs? cout << a;?

Comment: so after do  "i c[0] = a[1];" how can i delete that element in array a?

Comment: @Ryankid you can't fully delete it, but you can set it to `0` with `a[1] = 0`